# Can't connect flash to node.js on remote serve EC2r?

Tags: flash, node.js

I had flash talking to node.js via sockets on localhost, then I migrated it to EC2 instance with linux. Now I'm getting a sandbox security error, I tried using:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + host + ":" +  "1337");
```

But I can't seem to see any requests at all on the server. Also, I'm using Flashdevelop with "Use Network services" set to true. And on the server I installed a specific module for this called FlashPolicyFileServer, but I still can't get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 instance by default only enables ssh port (port 22), so you have to manually open the port (1337 in your case) you want in "Security Groups" setup menu.

Comment: Thanks! Should I just add this in my "default" Security Group?

Comment: Just add to the instance hosting your node app. Other instance may not need this port.

Comment: Yes, I only have one instance, but my instance already has default and quicklauch-1 security groups created. I guess I can add this rule on either of these? Or is my firewall only using one of these security groups?

Comment: In this case, just ignore the default one and config the one you defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try this as soon as possible see if it solves the problem